# How to check whether a screen is already created on the stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

Let's say I have a Bottom Nav Bar as below, and I have used `Navigator.pushNamed` in in viewing those screens through `onClick`.

[image: Example Bottom Nav Bar]

What I want to know is rather than having the `Navigator.pushNamed` on each of the button clicks in the NavBar buttons to navigate through the pages, is there a technique that can be used before executing the `Navigator.pushNamed` command to see whether there is an instance of the screen already created in the stack so that I can use the `Navigator.popUntil` method to have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tabbar widget in bottom navigation bar. I hope it will solve your current concerns.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car, color: Colors.black)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit, color: Colors.black)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike, color: Colors.black)),
              ],
          ),
          body: const TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```